# Error in UseMethod when Method Dispatching

Tags: r, r-s3, method-dispatch

I have tried the following code to create a method but when I use the generic function named "tutu" I receive the following error while the other functions (tutu.num and tutu.ch) work. Please can you help me to understand where is the mistake? I would expect that the "tutu" function recognize the class and use the appropriate method of the function that in the example is tutu.num. Thank you!

```
tutu.num<-function(x){x*100}
tutu.ch<-function(x){paste(x,"OK")}
tutu<-function(x){
  UseMethod("tutu")
}
vot<-1:5
tutu(vot)
```

Error in UseMethod("tutu") : 
  no applicable method for 'tutu' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the full class name after the period in your methods. In your example, the variable `vot` has class "numeric", but you only have methods defined for the classes "num" and "ch", neither of which exist. You need to define `tutu.numeric` and `tutu.character`. You can also define a `tutu.default` to handle objects of other unspecified classes:

```r
tutu           <- function(x) UseMethod("tutu")
tutu.default   <- function(x) return(NULL)
tutu.numeric   <- function(x) x * 100
tutu.character <- function(x) paste(x, "OK")

tutu(1:5)
#> [1] 100 200 300 400 500

tutu("method dispatch")
#> [1] "method dispatch OK"

tutu(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2))
#> NULL
```